# What is the difference between AMD Appzone and the original Bluestacks app player?

Tags: bluestacks

i would like to know what is the difference between these two ? Is AMD Appzone just a launcher, or appstore, or what ? They have different UI, but is that the only difference ?

Answer (score 3):

Bluestacks have entered a partnership with AMD, and released `AMD AppZone` which is powered by Bluestacks technology.
As [one article puts it:](http://www.slashgear.com/bluestacks-android-apps-on-pcs-made-simple-with-amd-appzone-player-27249531/)

> Another rather fabulous step towards total cross-platform compatibility has been made this week as the AMD AppZone Player is announced with full BlueStacks **power under the hood**.

[Here is one article](http://www.prweb.com/releases/2012/9/prweb9950117.htm) on the partnership.

> BlueStacks today announced a collaboration with AMD to launch AMD AppZone, the largest collection of Android apps which can be run on PCs. Powered by BlueStacks, the AMD AppZone Player brings hundreds of thousands of Android apps to the next generation of Windows 8 based slates, laptops, tablets and AiO desktop PCs. AMD AppZone is also available for AMD’s massive global installed base of Windows 7 based PCs. The collaboration with BlueStacks with optimizations for AMD GPU and APU technology enables a superior experience through AppZone on AMD powered PCs relative to other app stores like AppUp.

[Here is another article on it](http://www.androidpolice.com/2012/09/27/amd-re-launches-bluestacks-as-the-amd-appzone-complete-with-google-play-and-amazon-appstore-compatibility/) and an excerpt:

> BlueStacks made quite a splash when they released their alpha x86 Android app player for Windows late last year. When AMD invested millions of dollars into the company, it was clear that they were planning on leveraging the ever-expanding Android platform to put a shot into the arm of their PC chip business. Nearly a year after the initial investment, they're ready to make good: head on over to the official site to check out the shiny new AMD App Zone.

[AMD AppZone official site](http://www.amd.com/appzone)

Here is a link to the AMD AppZone  [App for Windows (Microsoft Site)](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/amd-appzone/50fbd1a9-de27-41c7-b6e8-72ddc0a199e7)

Comment: So, it is serving as an appstore, right ? And also, it provides some smoothness by working with AMD gpus.

Comment: Exactly, using Bluestacks technology and AMD as a partner to enhance it running on AMD chips, as it says above. It SHOULD be smoother, but as you know that's always relative and depends on hardware/software/setup etc in real life!